# Recreate a fabric/texture by using procedural lines and making them stand-out/high displacement/bump

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes, displacement, procedural, bump

I have been doing some research about what is the best way to recreate this image as a texture.

[image]
As you can see its a faux leather fabric with this frayed gazar denim stitched on top of it.

Only I want this frayed texture to stand out more/come to live, with ideally also having hair added onto to it.

I thought this could be possible by using Substance (image to texture)
or by creating this in GeoNodes by making a procedural striped texture.
Only for this I am lost how to connect the procedural stripes to the frayed gazar denim, also it could look too 2D and I want the denim to stand out/come forward.

Please let me know if you have any other ideas/recommendations!
You would help me a lot :))

(Edit)
I have tried this before with a different fabric which ended up looking like this, which was still too flat/2D. It was a transparent fabric with denim stitched on top of this.
[image: Previous try-out, only denim lines transparent texture]

Comment: Can you show us more about you progress in the research of this problem, like screenshot of the current stage in Blender or where you got stuck?

Comment: Hey thanks for your response :) I have tried this before with a different texture and it ended up looking like this, which is still too flat for me. I updated the question!

Comment: The pattern is very unique and needs thorough studying and finding repeatable elements. I think you should try sculpting the cloth patches to extract displacement and normal maps. Adding Hair particle system carefully combed here and there to make it look more three-dimensional. Or use the texture Alpha channel to control the particle emission. Also have a look at the Hair Geometry nodes. The complexity increases depending on how close up the the final render will be. Search Google with "Torn Fabric Textures Alphas Model" for inspiration.